# Prometheus Grafana Pod metrics

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, grafana, amazon-eks

We are using AWS EKS for deployment of our application in kubernetes cluster, using the AWS managed service for prometheus we have set up a grafana application.
However most of the metrics related to the application are not able to get any data,
The namespace is visible on some of the dashboards but it seems that none of the applications are captured by prometheus.
These are Java applications built on top of spring boot.
[image]

The above image shows up the namespace but no data is captured i tried many other dashboards but no luck.
Does this needs some changes in deployment.yaml of the application?

Any help on the same is highly appreciated.

V

Comment: 1. check the grafana data source 2.from data source you should directly open prometheus ui, check the configuration(pointing to which metrics endpoint).

Comment: Which vresion of Kubernetes did you use and how exactly did you setup your infrastructure? Please provide your yaml files.

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue ?  In my case, I am able to get CPU, Memory and Network usage if I select the option "ALL" and NOT for individual pods in Grafana